# PHP date() - inserting into an MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, date

I'm having a little bit of trouble with getting an incremented date into an MySQL database. The field is of type `DATE`.

First of all I increment the date with the following code:

```
if($_POST['membershipLength'] == "6 Months") {
    $renew = mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m")+9, date("d"), date("y"));
}
```

Then I wish to enter: `date("m/d/y", $renew)` into the column in the database.

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong? The value it inserts consists of 0s which I'm assuming is the default.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback everyone but it's still not working... the code can be viewed here: http://pastebin.com/ZKaCkWnK I'm prolly missing something real simple, right? Haha

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The MYSQL date field has the following format "Y-m-d" so something like "2010-11-04". You're trying to insert a value as "2010/04/11". Change your first parameter to "Y-m-d" and it should work :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
date ("Y-m-d H:i:s", $renew);
```

MySQL likes dates in a specific format.

Comment: The "H:i:s" is unnecessary if his column type is DATE and not DATETIME. MySQL would ignore it, I know, just being nitpicky ;)

Comment: No, not at all @Gazillion - good comment.  I just snagged the generic format, but in this case, date ("Y-m-d", $renew); is the optimum answer.

Answer (score 2):

the date format in MySQL is YYYY-MM-DD and you are inserting M-D-Y try with Y-M-D it will resolve your problem

Comment: That would do 2010-Jan-Sun, don't use capitalized letters for your month and day :)

Comment: you should pass the numbers like 2010-01-01 for jan and the date on the month DD is date of month like 05 , 13 , 22 , and have max of 30 or 31 as per month days and 29 or 28 for second month of year.

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code and working fine, other than one thing.  When you want to add 6 months, why are you adding 9 in months?

```
if($_POST['membershipLength'] == "6 Months") {



        $date = mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m")+6, date("d"), date("Y"));

        $renew = date("Y-m-d", $date);



    } elseif($_POST['membershipLength'] == "9 Months") {



        $date = mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m")+9, date("d"), date("Y"));

        $renew = date("Y-m-d", $date);



    } elseif($_POST['membershipLength'] == "12 Months") {



        $date = mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m")+12, date("d"), date("Y"));

        $renew = date("Y-m-d", $date);



    }
```

Comment: Ohh because 3 of those months is free so it stores a renew date into the database which consists of the free 3 and the selected membership time...

Are you using the date field type for this?

Comment: oh ok, in that case add 3 :)  Ya, Im using date field

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your help everyone. The mistake I was making in addition the corrections you all suggested was that I was checking for a value that didn't match. Silly me!